# Is there a way to fix my charger so that it charges my laptop, or must I buy a new one?

Tags: laptop, battery, acer-aspire, charging, charger

My Lite-On PA-1900-32 charger has ceased being able to charge my Acer Aspire Timeline U laptop. I cannot think of any immediate reason for this to be the case. For a while, charging was sketchy and I had to manipulate the charger into a certain position for my laptop to charge. Then, one day, I found that I could not charge at all.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Peter Note I have now changed the title. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had to manipulate the charger in different positions and could produce a charge to the battery if moved in just the right way then you have two possibilities:

1) The charger itself is faulty near the plug

or

2) The jack in the computer is damaged.

I'd try using a different power supply first as that is much easier to rule out. If a known working power supply doesn't fix the issue then most likely it is the jack inside the laptop.

Comment: Another Acer charger works with my laptop. So I guess the charger itself is faulty.

Comment: Great to hear! Please select this as the best answer if it worked for you!

Comment: Sure, will do shortly. But does that mean I need to buy a new charger? I was hoping there would be some way to fix my old one. New chargers of the kind I need cost $29 at the cheapest price. Sure, I could buy a new one, but how can I guarantee that the same thing won't happen to my new charger?

Comment: Buy a new charger? I would. What is most likely compromised is where the tip meets with the contacts which meets with the wiring. To get to the portion that is compromised you would need to shave down the plastic/rubber that is on the tip to expose the connections. Adapters were never meant for this and doing so would compromise the solid plastic structure which is meant to keep the connections in place.